# manifest for salesforce/salesforcedx:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker, code-builder, codespaces

I am trying to create a [Codespace](https://github.com/features/codespaces) using the [Salesforce Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/salesforce/salesforcedx), but I am getting this error:

> manifest for salesforce/salesforcedx:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

I have a repo with a folder called:

```
.devcontainer
```

With two files:

1. devcontainer.json
2. Dockerfile

The **devcontainer.json** file contains:

```
{
    "name": "SFDX Project (Docker)",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "extensions": [
      "salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode",
      "redhat.vscode-xml",
      "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
      "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
    }
}
```

And the **Dockerfile** file contains:

```
FROM salesforce/salesforcedx
```

Yet, when I create a Codespace from the repo, I get these errors in the log file:

```
Configuration starting...
2021-08-15T06:03:13: $ git -C "/var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace" clone --depth 1 https://github.com/My-Company/Codespace-Docker-Test "/var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test"
2021-08-15T06:03:13: Cloning into '/var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test'...
2021-08-15T06:03:13: git process exited with exit code 0
2021-08-15T06:03:16: $ git -C "/var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test" config --local remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
2021-08-15T06:03:16: git process exited with exit code 0
2021-08-15T06:03:16: ApplicationInsights:An invalid instrumentation key was provided. There may be resulting telemetry loss [ 'AIF-d9b70cd4-b9f9-4d70-929b-a071c400b217' ]
[2021-08-15T06:03:17.002Z] @microsoft/vscode-dev-containers-cli 0.42.0.
[2021-08-15T06:03:17.002Z] Start: Resolving Remote
[2021-08-15T06:03:17.045Z] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=Type=codespaces
[2021-08-15T06:03:17.083Z] Stop (38 ms): Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=Type=codespaces
[2021-08-15T06:03:17.087Z] Start: Run: docker build -f /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test/.devcontainer/Dockerfile -t vsc-codespace-docker-test-b38e07552bcd437ae10ac71c79d88da2 /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test/.devcontainer
[2021-08-15T06:03:17.123Z] Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB

[2021-08-15T06:03:17.173Z] Step 1/1 : FROM salesforce/salesforcedx
[2021-08-15T06:03:18.754Z] manifest for salesforce/salesforcedx:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Error: Command failed: docker build -f /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test/.devcontainer/Dockerfile -t vsc-codespace-docker-test-b38e07552bcd437ae10ac71c79d88da2 /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test/.devcontainer
    at q5 (/usr/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/vscode-dev-containers-cli/dist/node/devContainersCLI.js:279:9340)
    at async k5 (/usr/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/vscode-dev-containers-cli/dist/node/devContainersCLI.js:279:7692)
    at async lL (/usr/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/vscode-dev-containers-cli/dist/node/devContainersCLI.js:279:4237)
    at async i8 (/usr/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/vscode-dev-containers-cli/dist/node/devContainersCLI.js:247:9700)
    at async $G (/usr/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/vscode-dev-containers-cli/dist/node/devContainersCLI.js:293:7173)
    at async Kae (/usr/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/vscode-dev-containers-cli/dist/node/devContainersCLI.js:293:26145)
    at async Yae (/usr/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/vscode-dev-containers-cli/dist/node/devContainersCLI.js:293:25739)
[2021-08-15T06:03:18.757Z] Stop (1670 ms): Run: docker build -f /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test/.devcontainer/Dockerfile -t vsc-codespace-docker-test-b38e07552bcd437ae10ac71c79d88da2 /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test/.devcontainer
Failed to create container.Error: Command failed: docker build -f /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test/.devcontainer/Dockerfile -t vsc-codespace-docker-test-b38e07552bcd437ae10ac71c79d88da2 /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/Codespace-Docker-Test/.devcontainerError Code: 1302Container creation failed.
2021-08-15T06:03:18: Creating recovery container.
2021-08-15T06:03:18:
```

Why is the docker image not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Change the contents of the **Dockerfile** to:

```
FROM salesforce/salesforcedx:latest-rc-full
```

I imagine once `Code Builder` is officially released the value `FROM salesforce/salesforcedx` will be supported

Before I figured out the above, I also got it working with the below solution.

**Alternative Solution**

Change the contents of the **Dockerfile** to:

```
FROM heroku/heroku:18

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG SALESFORCE_CLI_VERSION=latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo '2d316e55994086e41761b0c657e0027e9d16d7160d3f8854cc9dc7615b99a526  ./nodejs.tar.gz' > node-file-lock.sha \
  && curl -s -o nodejs.tar.gz https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.2/node-v12.18.2-linux-x64.tar.gz \
  && shasum --check node-file-lock.sha
RUN mkdir /usr/local/lib/nodejs \
  && tar xf nodejs.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib/nodejs/ --strip-components 1 \
  && rm nodejs.tar.gz node-file-lock.sha
ENV PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/bin:$PATH
RUN npm install --global sfdx-cli@${SALESFORCE_CLI_VERSION}

RUN apt-get install --assume-yes \
  openjdk-11-jdk-headless \
  jq

RUN apt-get autoremove --assume-yes \
  && apt-get clean --assume-yes \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV SFDX_CONTAINER_MODE true
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog
ENV SHELL /bin/bash
```

Comment: You can find all the other tags/versions here: https://hub.docker.com/r/salesforce/salesforcedx/tags 

I would caution against copying the full Dockerfile like you did above because then you'll need to copy and paste it again every time there's an update (eg. now they're using node 16 instead of your pinned 12).